# ifortvars_intel64.sh does not exist

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I got an Intel fortran code but the compile file doesn't run.

It has following lines.

```
# Set up environment variables for Mac and Intel Fortan 11.0
source /Developer/opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/089/bin/intel64/ifortvars_intel64.sh
```

However, although I looked into everything inside "intel" folder, I can't find that file "ifortvars_intel64.sh"

What should I do?

Comment: do you have an `ifortvars.sh` or a `compilervars.sh` somewhere?

Comment: use the find in a the finder window.

Comment: @Gilles  I could find ifortvars.sh but could not find compilervars.sh... What should I do?

Comment: try `source /path/to/ifortvars.sh intel64`

Comment: @Gilles  I mean I directly looked into the folder in the computer but could not find ifortvars.sh  .  Is this hidden file? Or administrator access is required? Or.. why can't I see it?

Comment: Ok I don't get it: what environment file do you have? Please add to your question the output of `find /Developer/opt/intel/ -name "*vars*.sh"`

Comment: That /Developer in the path looks odd - Intel Fortran doesn't install there. Usually to /opt/intel. ifortvars,sh should be there if the product is installed - you should not be calling ifortvars_intel64.sh but instead use the "source" command Gilles posted above. It could be that whoever installed Intel Fortran on your system didn't install the 64-bit version. 11.1 is from a long time ago, though!